# Cannot submit new version of ios app - "An App ID with Identifier 'com.yyy.app' is not available. Please enter a different string."

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

This might look duplicate as there are in-numerous questions raised with the same subject, but mine is slightly tedious, I am getting this error in xcode or creating manual certificate in Apple Developer Central.

I am one of the admin of an existing app in iYunes, the initial version was submitted by another developer and I am trying to submit a new version. I even sought the other developer's help to upload my new version but he is getting the same error.

Comment: check in your Xcode-accounts,is it configured with your apple id(same team id of previous version).?

Answer (score 0):

I had identical problem. Also another developers were creating app before and then I got to publish new features to existing app. I was trying to solve this for whole week and nothing worked.

The solution to my problem was deleting all provisioning profiles that were created before and creating new one. I made sure I deleted every single one that was not used or was old to really make it clean.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I did that earlier with no luck before i came here :(